# MySQL 5.7 vs 8 - only_full_group_by behaviour

Tags: mysql

I have a local, 5.7 database, where, with only_full_group_by enabled, the following query quite rightly fails:

```
 select
 p.oid, p.idsex, c.codetext
 from p_person as p
 join codes as c on p.idsex = c.proid and c.dictcode = 0
 group by p.oid
 ;
```

However, it runs fine under v8 (and, yes, I checked the mode was enabled).

I wondered if this was an enhancement under v8, since the codes table has a unique index on proid+dictcode, ensuring that we can only ever return a single value (i.e. mysql then treats c.codetext as a field in p_person). I note that the code breaks as expected under v8 when I remove "and c.dictcode = 0".

Any insights appreciated - thanks in advance.

(Oh, and just to clarify, oid is the primary key on p_person)

Comment: I think that feature must not be in the older version ?  I might be wrong but would make sense.  Would it be out of the question to upgrade your database to 8 ?  Heck 8.30 is out now ..

Comment: tbh, as 'features' go, I'm not sure I like this one. I mean, if it's basing it off indexes, then I guess it's pretty clever, but IMHO it smacks of IE being too lenient with bad HTML (which just led to a proliferation of bad HTML).

As for upgrading, most of the sites we support are still on 5.7, but eventually, yes, I'll be upgrading my local system once the majority of our customers are upgraded.

Comment: That makes sense, yeah as long as no new things are being deployed in the old version you should be good.  But man, I have had similar situations where the client wanted to save 2 dollars a month on a cheaper linux box runn 5.7 and I'm just thinking man, if you can't afford 2 more dollars a month to make managing this thing easier, you really can't afford what its going to cost to pay someone to do it either.

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE for both tables. The best way - provide a fiddle which reproduces the issue.

Comment: @easleyfixed - By the end of this month (October 2023) a valid response to that client is, "MySQL 5.7 has ended support, and any security bugs will not be fixed. We need to use MySQL 8.0 from now on."

Comment: @TomMelly, It's possible that the detection of functional dependencies was improved in MySQL 8.0. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html for details. As Akina suggested, if you post the CREATE TABLE for both tables (or a dbfiddle), then we may be able to comment on the difference.

Comment: Now THAT is what I like to hear :)

Comment: From the link that @BillKarwin posted, I think he's got the answer (or at least the link has). It strongly implies that in the case I posted, V8 is more 'intelligent', and doesn't barf when the 1-to-1 relationship is absolute.

Comment: Not surprising, but I didn't go to the trouble of comparing that manual page word-for-word with the same page in the MySQL 5.7 manual. I'll leave that to you. :-)